# How to create custom page on Front-Office with a module on prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have created the button A on product details page. When click A button, it will redirect to my custom page.
But I don't know how to do that on Prestashop 1.7

I have used same:

```
$this->setTemplate('custom.tpl');
```

but seems it can not working.

Please help me or any ideas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a separate controller for that in your module at the following path:

/modules/supercheckout/controllers/front/fcont.php (where supercheckout is your module name)

and write the following code in the file:

```
class SupercheckoutFcontModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

public function initContent()
{
        parent::initContent();
                $this->setTemplate('module:supercheckout/views/templates/front/order_detail.tpl');
}

}
```

You can use the following code to fetch URL of above controller:

```
$this->context->link->getModuleLink('supercheckout', 'fcont');
```

Comment: Thank you.I have used same you but my custom page can not load header and footer of theme.

Comment: you have to extend the layout block in your TPL file, for reference you can see TPL file of any existing module.

Answer (score 0):

For those having similar problem. The [solution in this article](https://victor-rodenas.com/2017/04/23/crear-pagina-php-en-prestashop-1-7/) was tested on PS 1.7 and 1.7.4 and still works. Translate this page from French and follow carefully. All you need to do is to create a new file for controller.php and then place new .tpl file in your theme's folder. At the end, you assign the URL in SEO tab in PS admin and you can call your new custom page in front-end from http://yoursiteaddress.com/index.php?controller=yourname

I don't take ANY credits for the solution, all the hats off to Victor (victor-rodenas.com) for the solution which I tested on PS 1.7.4.

## prestashop #custom #page #bespoke #tpl